# lapply and function arguments with different scope

Tags: r, lapply, glm

I encountered strange behavior when using lapply to bootstrap a GLM. Each iteration of the lapply uses a different weight, but the formula variable is the same. Thus, the latter was kept outside the anonymous function.

Below is a reproducible toy example.

The following code runs as expected:

```
library(dplyr)
data_adult <-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guru99-edu/R-Programming/master/adult.csv")
data_adult$Y  <- (data_adult$hours.per.week > 40)

est_boot <- lapply(1:10, function(bb){
                       ff  <- as.formula('Y ~ gender')
                       w  <-  rexp( nrow(data_adult), 1)
                       glmout  <- glm( ff,  'quasibinomial', data_adult, w )
                       return(coef(glmout))
})
```

Whereas the following does not:

```
ff  <- as.formula('Y ~ gender')
est_boot <- lapply(1:10, function(bb){
                       w  <-  rexp( nrow(data_adult), 1)
                       glmout  <- glm( ff,  'quasibinomial', data_adult, w )
                       return(coef(glmout))
})
Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'w' not found
```

I thought maybe the function needs all the arguments to defined locally. However, data_adult is not. Why is `w` not recognized when `ff` is defined outside the function?

I am using R 4.3.0.

Comment: Maybe add `w` to data_adult, i.e. `data_adult$w <- rexp...` or define `ff` as a character string and then use `formula(ff)` as the first argument to `glm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, a formula has an attribute called `.Environment` which you can see in your second version by calling

```r
attributes(ff)
#> $class
#> [1] "formula"
#> 
#> $.Environment
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

When a formula is parsed, the `.Environment` attribute is used as a starting point on the search path to find the variables it references. The formula cannot find `w` because it does not exist in the global environment. You can get round this by assigning the local environment to the `.Environment` attribute inside `lapply`

```r
ff  <- as.formula('Y ~ gender')

est_boot <- lapply(1:10, function(bb){
  w  <-  rexp( nrow(data_adult), 1)
  environment(ff) <- environment()
  glmout  <- glm(ff,  'quasibinomial', data_adult, w )
  return(coef(glmout))
})
```

Comment: Wow, very nice. Thank you! Out of curiosity, is there an obvious setting where this would be a helpful feature of a formula? Can't think of a case where I would not want the local environment.

Comment: @The_Anomaly The error is actually thrown inside `model.frame.default`, which uses the formula's environment to evaluate the symbols in the call to `glm`. I'm not sure of the design rationale of evaluating the model frame with the formula's environment rather than using the calling frame; they are almost always the same of course. It may simply be that `model.frame` is used by a lot of functions, and having formulas is the most convenient way of unobtrusively passing the (likely) calling environment around.